How to run elevated powershell in VSCode via remote tunnels?

I have local VSCode instance connected to remote windows VSCode server.
Powershell running remotely via tunnel does not have admin priveleges.
However when I run VSCode directly on remote windows machine the powershell has admin priveleges.

I have set VSCode.exe and bin/code-tunnel.exe to run as Administrator.
